# Custom Field Validation in Facebook Login Plugin

Tags: php, facebook

I want to implement a "Login with Facebook" button. I want to add a new custom field (a username field) for users to complete on their first login. Also I need to perform validation on that field to make sure that the username isn't taken. PHP is my language of choice.

Comment: Is there any reason why you dont want to have the username processing as a separate functionality? I mean, you can log the user in with FB credentials and on the second step, ask him/her to enter the username and check. Wont that work?

Comment: So are you looking to have the user fill out a username, validate the username, and then connect with FB? What is the problem?

Comment: @Garrett Smallwood, no, I'm looking to have the user enter his Facebook login info and in the same field enter a username.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did something very similar, but with FB's registration plugin. Here is a pretty good tutorial from which you can probably take a cue or two : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/advanced/

Comment: Thanks for the link @sniper, looks exactly like what I need!